# Failure Building 32-bit Package in 64-bit Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, packaging, deb

I am creating a 32-bit binary only package which in an Ubuntu environment which is 64-bit. I've install ia32-libs already, but when I run:

> debuild -ai386 -b

I get the following error:

> dh_strip Can't exec "i686-linux-gnu-strip": No such file or directory
>   at /usr/share/perl5/Debian/Debhelper/Dh_Lib.pm line 215. dh_strip:
>   i686-linux-gnu-strip --remove-section=.comment --remove-section=.note
>   --strip-unneeded PATH_TO_LIB_IN_PACKAGE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found was to have two virtual systems one with a 32-bit install and one with a 64-bit install.

Comment: No, you can use chrooted environment